# Button that changes a variable and creates a new button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make something along the lines of a text based game, but using buttons instead of text for input. For example, I want to start with 3 buttons on a page. When you choose one of the buttons, a function should then change that questions variable, and then create the buttons for the next question.

Question one:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<button onclick="russetPotato()">Russet</button>
<button onclick="redPotato()">Red</button>
<button onclick="sweetPotato()">Sweet</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var seed = 0;
var soil = 0;
function russetPotato(){
    seed = 1
    document.write("You set seed as Russet Potato.");
}
function redPotato(){
    seed = 2
    document.write("You set seed as Red Potato.");
}
function sweetPotato(){
    soil = 3
    document.write("You set seed as Sweet Potato.");
}
</script>
</html>
```

Now what I want to do is add in the second question. How is it that I can make the soil buttons appear after the seed buttons have been answered instead of them all appearing at the same time?

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="russetPotato()">Russet</button>
    <button onclick="redPotato()">Red</button>
    <button onclick="sweetPotato()">Sweet</button>
    <button onclick="sandySoil()">Thin Sandy Soil</button>
    <button onclick="loamSoil()">Loose Loam Soil</button>
    <button onclick="claySoil()">Heavy Clay Soil</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var seed = 0;
    var soil = 0;
    function russetPotato(){
        seed = 1
        document.write("You set seed as Russet Potato.");
    }
    function redPotato(){
        seed = 2
        document.write("You set seed as Red Potato.");
    }
    function sweetPotato(){
        soil = 1
        document.write("You set seed as Sweet Potato.");
    }
    function sandySoil(){
        soil = 1
        document.write("You set soil as Thin Sandy Soil.");
    }
    function loamSoil(){
        soil = 2
        document.write("You set soil as Loose Loam Soil.");
    }
    function claySoil(){
        soil = 3
        document.write("You set soil as Heavy Clay Soil.");
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Apologies if this is actually something very simple. This is my first experimentation with javascript/html.

Comment: You can't `document.write` below the closing `</body>` tag. You shouldn't use `docement.write` anyways, because that can't be used with XHTML, and you want reusable code. Really use should use external JavaScript in the `<head>` and have your code execute `onload` because the `<script>` tag being in the `<body>` makes the `document.body` not available in some older Browsers.

Comment: use `CreateElement()` or `.add()` jquery function for adding dynamic HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create new buttons (in the case you use always three of them). Anyways it depends all on the game logic.
Usually how it's done is by using an Array of Objects literal like:

```
var stages = [
  [
   {btntext:"Russet", type:"seed", pts:1, text:"You set seed as Russet Potato."},
   {btntext:"Red", type:"seed", pts:2, text:"You set seed as Russet Potato."},
   {btntext:"Sweet", type:"soil", pts:1, text:"You set seed as Russet Potato."}
  ],[
   {btntext:"Sand", type:"foo", pts:1, text:"You set soil as Thin Sandy Soil."},
   {btntext:"Loam", type:"bar", pts:2, text:"You set soil as Loose Loam Soil."},
   {btntext:"Clay", type:"bar", pts:3, text:"You set soil as Heavy Clay Soil."}
  ],[
   {btntext:"Baz", type:"baz", pts:1, text:"You set Baz!."},
   {btntext:"Foo2", type:"foo", pts:2, text:"You set Foo twice!."}
  ]
];
```

Now, if you look the above Array and do: `alert(stages.length) // 3` you'll see you can count `3` stages. If you set a `var counter = 0` initially to `0` you can first read the `0` indexed stage, read the length of stage *options* like `var nOfBtns = stages[counter].length; // 3` cause you have three options *Russet Red Sweet*. The last one will return you 2 buttons. You can extract all the needed values from your Array and Object really easily like:

```
 var selectedButtonPoints = stages[counter][buttonNid].pts;
```

Once the player clicks the buttons and you extract all the needed info from your array, you simply create a new set of buttons depending on the number of items in the next stage and increase the counter `counter += 1;`

Just to give you an idea.

Also, document.write is deprecated. See how to use `innerHTML` instead.
 Set some elements on your page like some containers:

```
<div id="buttons"></div> <!-- JS will populate with needed buttons -->
<div id="points"></div> <!-- JS will write here the player stats -->
<!-- etc... -->
```

Target those elements with JS, create functions like `function createNewButtons()` and use them to fill your elements with buttons and info.